# How to add 10 seconds in current_timestamp SQL ( Oracle )

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I want to add 10 seconds to `current_timestamp` in my PL/SQL script. I tried below code but it's output is not in timestamp format.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1/24/60/6 FROM dual;
```

**Output:**

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1/24/60/6

---------------------------
28-AUG-15
```

Is there any function similar to TIMESTAMPADD in Mysql server?

Comment: You code should work, so your tool is probably just truncating the time portion of the result.  I would write the logic as `(10 /  (24*60*60))`.  I think that makes the intention more obvious.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Oracle, if you want a `timestamp` as the result, rather than a `date` (a `date` always includes the time to the second, though, so you may just want a `date`), you'd want to add an `interval` to the `timestamp`.  There are various ways to construct an interval-- you can use an interval literal

```
select current_timestamp + interval '10' second
  from dual
```

or you could use the `numtodsinterval` function

```
select current_timestamp + numToDSInterval( 10, 'second' )
  from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by using `TO_CHAR`

```
Select TO_CHAR(current_timestamp,'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:SS') AS TIMESTAMP,
TO_CHAR(current_timestamp+10/24/60/60,'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:SS') AS TIMESTAMP_PLUS_10SEC
from dual;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   TIMESTAMP         TIMESTAMP_PLUS_10SEC
31-08-15 05:17:19     31-08-15 05:17:29
```