# how to add second in oracle timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-rds

How can I add seconds with timestamp value in Oracle. 
I tried this ....

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+200 AS addedTime FROM dual
```

But by this I am getting this

2018-06-04 19:03:01 => 2018-12-21 19:03:01 (after adding 200)

As you can see date is getting added , but I want to add second only...

This SQL running properly in DB2 , can any one suggest me any suitable alternative in Oracle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 10 seconds in current\_timestamp SQL ( Oracle )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277369/how-to-add-10-seconds-in-current-timestamp-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 6):

You could always use fraction(for Oracle 1 = 1 day):

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 200 *(1/24/60/60) AS addedTime 
FROM dual;
<=>
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 200/86400 FROM dual
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78e6f67320d727578d24daf644e8b710)**

or:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '200' SECOND FROM dual
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle date/time arithmetic is expressed in terms of days. So adding `200` adds 200 days to an Oracle `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` object. If you want to add seconds you can either use intervals or you can add fractional days. Personally, for something as granular as seconds I prefer to use intervals; anything from hours and up I use regular date arithmetic or `ADD_MONTHS()` (interval months and years are particularly dangerous as they are not leap-year safe, while `ADD_MONTHS()` is).

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '200' SECOND FROM dual;
```

Note that the single quotes around the interval value are necessary; `INTERVAL 200 SECOND` will raise an error.

Hope this helps.