# How do you add X seconds to multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update test1
set start_date = sysdate
where table_id between 223 and 228;
```

I want to update date of these in increment of x seconds.

So

- table_id 223 has 2018-08-19 09:10:15
- table_id 224 has 2018-08-19 09:10:25
- table_id 225 has 2018-08-19 09:10:35

something like that. How should I proceed this? I am using sql developer and I have been updating one by one. I am not allow to make procedure on database or make another programs to do so, so I have to use update query to do this. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See answers  to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277369/how-to-add-10-seconds-in-current-timestamp-sql-oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add 10 seconds in current\_timestamp SQL ( Oracle )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277369/how-to-add-10-seconds-in-current-timestamp-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
SQL> create table test1
  2    (table_id number,
  3     start_date date
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1 (table_id)
  2    select 220 + level
  3    from dual
  4    connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> update test1 set
  2    start_date = sysdate + (10 / (24 * 60 * 60)) * rownum
  3  where table_id between 223 and 228;

6 rows updated.

SQL> select * From test1 order by table_id;

  TABLE_ID START_DATE
---------- -------------------
       221
       222
       223 19.08.2018 09:29:47
       224 19.08.2018 09:29:57
       225 19.08.2018 09:30:07
       226 19.08.2018 09:30:17
       227 19.08.2018 09:30:27
       228 19.08.2018 09:30:37
       229
       230

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

In this example, in `(10 / (24 * 60 * 60)) * rownum`

- 10 represents the increment (10 seconds)
- 24 * 60 * 60 is number of seconds in a day (24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds)
- rownum is used as a multiplier so that each row gets its own 10 seconds increment

Answer (score 1):

This query uses the 'numToDSInterval()' function to turn the row number of the result set into an interval of ten seconds:

```
update test
set start_date = sysdate + 
                 numToDSInterval ( ((rownum-1) * 10), 'second')
where table_id between 223 and 228
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use some simple math to calculate the offset of each record using the ID if it is a numeric one as you state like this (not familiar to Oracle SQL), but this would be the general idea:

```
UPDATE test1
   SET start_date = current_timestamp + numToDSInterval( 10 * (id - 223), 'second' )
 WHERE table_id >= 223 AND table_id <= 228
```

Answer (score 0):

Another but similar way to do this

```
update test1 set start_date = sysdate + numToDSInterval(10 * (table_id - rownum), 'second')
where table_id >= 223 and table_id <= 228;
```