# Oracle random time and interval

Tags: sql, oracle, random, intervals

I'm looking to generate times to create a schedule, which has multiple locations that need to be checked.

Picture a prison guard who has to walk around a jail and check every cell. The schedule will start at some random time MMDDYYYY HH24:MI and then has between 6 - 10 minutes to check the next cell, after that 6 - 10 minutes to check the cell after that and so on and so until the schedule is completed.

Let me illustrate with a simple example.

Schedule_id location_id
Schedule_time

1 100 07132020 16:10:00

-- start of schedule

1 103 07132020 16:07:00

-- guard has to be at location 103 by 16:07

1 110 07132020 16:16:00

-- guard has to be at location 110 by 16:16

Since I randomly generated 3 rows for schedule 1 this is completed then I create the next  schedule.

-- start of schedule but say I randomly GENERATED 5 rows for this schedule.

2 102 07132020 23:46:00

-- guard has to be at location 102 by 23:46

2 104 07132020 23:56:00

-- guard has to be at location 104 by 23:56

-- WAIT!! I've generated 5 rows for schedule 2 but the next interval will cross midnight so I stop with 2 rows then go on to create the next schedule at some random HH24:MI but the MMDDYYYY will still be the same 07132020.

THE STOP GAP is either we populated the rows with times OR it can't cross midnight!!

-- start of new schedule. Note same MMDDYYYY

3 223 07132020 02:04:00

3 143 07132020 02:11:00

3 46 07132020 02:17:00

Your first example was almost there except there was NO STOP GAP from preventing it from crossing midnight and generating the next schedule.

I have a location table too where I want to randomly choose a location_id but I can't use dbms_random since the values aren't consecutively numbered. I will try and figure that out. I'm mentioning it to complete the scenario.

```
 CREATE TABLE schedule_hdr AS
SELECT level AS schedule_id,
   'Schedule ' || level AS schedule_name

 FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 10;



CREATE TABLE  locations(
location_id NUMBER(4), 
location_name VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO locations (
location_id, 
location_name 
)
VALUES 
(46, 'Door 1');

INSERT INTO locations (
location_id, 
location_name 
)
VALUES 
(143, 'Door 2');

INSERT INTO locations (
location_id, 
location_name 
)
VALUES 
(223, 'Door 3');

WITH random_times (     schedule_id,    schedule_name, datetime, lvl ) AS (
SELECT schedule_id,
     schedule_name, 
     TRUNC(sysdate)
     + NUMTODSINTERVAL( FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,23*60)), 'MINUTE' ),
     1
  FROM   schedule_hdr
 UNION ALL
 SELECT schedule_id,
     schedule_name, 
     datetime + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,11)), 'MINUTE'),
     lvl + 1
  FROM   random_times
  WHERE  lvl < 5
)
SELECT schedule_id,
   schedule_name,
   datetime
FROM   random_times
   ORDER BY schedule_id, datetime;
```

My initial attempt  but the date is. always random and there is no interval

```
WITH rws  as (     select level rn from   dual connect by level <= 5 ), 
   scheds as ( select sh.*, round (dbms_random.value(1,5) ) n from schedule_hdr sh )
  select   schedule_id,
  TRUNC(sysdate) + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400
  from   rws 
  join   scheds s  on rn <= n
  Order by schedule_id;
```

Comment: Does DBMS_RANDOM take in a seed? Use the timer in MS as a seed for Random number generator to get a truly random value.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select trunc(sysdate) + floor(dbms_random.value(0, 1) * 19*60*60) * interval '1' second
from dual;
```

This generates a number of seconds and then adds that to the date.

One way to see the time is to convert the value to a string:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + floor(dbms_random.value(0, 1) * 19*60*60) * interval '1' second, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes the whole sequence:

```
--seconds 0    
--minutes increment: 6-10    
--start: 00:00 - 18:59    
--start integer between 0 and 19*60-1

with first_value as (
select trunc(sysdate) + (abs(mod(dbms_random.random, (19*60-1)))/(24*60)) first_date_value from dual
),
other_values (next_date_value, lvl) as (
select first_date_value, 0 from first_value fv
union all
select ov.next_date_value + (round(dbms_random.value(6,10)) / (24*60)), ov.lvl + 1 from first_value fv join other_values ov on ov.next_date_value < to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') || ' 18:49', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') 
)
select * from other_values;
```

It uses a CTE to create a first value and then provide a list until no more values are possible. I'm computing a random minute from 0 to 18*60+59 for the start value. Then I have a recursive CTE that increments the previous value between 6 and 10 minutes. There's a stopping condition for the recursion at 18:49. The next increment should still allow a value smaller than 18:59

Comment: Looks good. A few questions if you don't mind. To get the time in my code can I just merge your code and reference the column next_date_val. Second, what will happen if I need a million values? It looks like the times generate will not reset. That is why I mentioned a random value for the first member in the group than use the INCREMENT for the rest of the members in the group

Comment: Everytime you run the query it will provide a new set of values. Always starting at sometime during the day, before 18:59. Then it will create random increments. Those random increments are between 6 and 10 minutes. There will be as many rows as possible until the time 18:59 of the day is met. You can rerun the query as many times as you like, each time with a different starting time and different increments.

Comment: You had one requirement to have 0 seconds. And that requirement is met in two different ways. One way is fine obviously, it's rather to see different techniques. The first one, for the starting date is to have a random minute value in the allowed range. Then the minutes are converted to a part of the day (divide by 24 * 60). The second way to achieve 0 seconds is to have a decimal random value between 6 and 10 and have the result rounded in order to shave off the seconds. Then that value is again converted to a part of the day (divide by 24*60)

Comment: If you want to have those random values for a different day than today, you just have to change the `sysdate` part in the CTE `first_value` with the day you like.

Comment: If you want to have a million intervals since the starting date, obviously the constraint of all the values being smaller than 18:59 needs to be replaced by something like `on ov.lvl < 999999`

Comment: On integrating it with other queries: exactly, you just reference the next_date_val column.

Comment: @Beefstu Using `ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,10))` gives an uneven distribution and you will get half as many 6 or 10 minute intervals as you would 7, 8, or 9 minute intervals.

Comment: @casenonsensitive `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM` was deprecated with Oracle 11gR1 and [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67499) states it should not be used.

Comment: @MT0: yes and yes. But using floor(dbms_random.value(6, 10)) wouldn't work either, as the 10 case would happen very seldom. What would work and return a rather even distribution is `mod(floor(dbms_random.value(0, 5)), 5) + 6`

Comment: Using `6,10` would never generate a value of 10. You need to use `FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 6, 11 ) )`.

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that it would be an including range. But the documentation states otherwise meaning dbms_random.value(6, 11) the 11 is never returned.

Comment: @casenomsenstive Sorry to bother you and let me know if I should start a new question but I'm  looking at your response and want to do this except after 20 rows can I stop before the next entry passes midnight? My goal is to pass in an end time and stop before I hit that. I think I can convert to a procedure and do that myself.

select timestamp '2021-08-20 14:00:00' + numtodsinterval(rownum*10,'MINUTE')
    from dual
    connect by level <= 20;

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
select 
    TRUNC(TRUNC(sysdate) + dbms_random.value(0, 1) * INTERVAL '19:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'MI') 
from dual;
```

Comment: The random value will always be [less than the `high` argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_RANDOM.html#GUID-AAD9E936-D74F-440D-9E16-24F3F0DE8D31) so this will never generate a time of `18:59`. Instead the interval being multiplied by should be `INTERVAL '19:00' HOUR TO MINUTE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NUMTODSINTERVAL( <random_amount>, 'MINUTE' )` to generate an interval of just minutes. Couple this with a recursive sub-query factoring clause and you can generate 5 rows for each row in `schedule_hdr`:

```sql
WITH random_times ( schedule_id, schedule_name, datetime, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT schedule_id,
         schedule_name, 
         TRUNC(sysdate)
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,19*60)), 'MINUTE' ),
         1
  FROM   schedule_hdr
UNION ALL
  SELECT schedule_id,
         schedule_name, 
         datetime + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,11)), 'MINUTE'),
         lvl + 1
  FROM   random_times
  WHERE  lvl < 5
)
SELECT schedule_id,
       schedule_name,
       datetime
FROM   random_times
ORDER BY schedule_id, datetime;
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schedule_hdr (schedule_id, schedule_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Schedule 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Schedule 2' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> SCHEDULE_ID | SCHEDULE_NAME | DATETIME           
> ----------: | :------------ | :------------------
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 05:13:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 05:23:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 05:32:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 05:38:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 05:45:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 10:56:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 11:02:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 11:09:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 11:19:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 11:29:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=12b6e4e234f4824cd7a5c9b29c4535e9)*

---

## Update

> I ALWAYS need the MMDDYYYY to be the same for all rows. So can the code be adjusted to reset the start time WHEN the schedule_id changes.

Generate one set of rows and the `CROSS JOIN` with your table:

```sql
WITH random_times ( datetime, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,19*60)), 'MINUTE' ),
         1
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT datetime + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,11)), 'MINUTE'),
         lvl + 1
  FROM   random_times
  WHERE  lvl < 5
)
SELECT sh.schedule_id,
       sh.schedule_name,
       rt.datetime
FROM   schedule_hdr sh
       CROSS JOIN random_times rt
ORDER BY schedule_id, datetime;
```

This gives:

> ```
> SCHEDULE_ID | SCHEDULE_NAME | DATETIME           
> ----------: | :------------ | :------------------
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 13:43:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 13:49:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 13:56:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 14:03:00
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-11 14:10:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 13:43:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 13:49:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 13:56:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 14:03:00
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-11 14:10:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dde7392925545bba4d15706a6dc925f8)*

---

## Update 2

```sql
WITH indexed_locations ( num, name ) AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(), id ),
         name
  FROM   locations
),
random_times ( schedule_id, schedule_name, datetime, lvl, max_lvl, max_doors ) AS (
  SELECT schedule_id,
         schedule_name,
         TRUNC(sysdate)
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,24*60)), 'MINUTE' ),
         1,
         FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,11)),
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations )
  FROM   schedule_hdr
UNION ALL
  SELECT schedule_id,
         schedule_name,
         datetime + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(6,11)), 'MINUTE'),
         lvl + 1,
         max_lvl,
         max_doors
  FROM   random_times
  WHERE  lvl < max_lvl
)
SELECT rt.schedule_id,
       rt.schedule_name,
       rt.datetime,
       il.name AS door_name
FROM   random_times rt
       INNER JOIN indexed_locations il
       ON ( FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 1, rt.max_doors + 1 ) ) = il.num )
WHERE  rt.datetime < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
ORDER BY schedule_id, datetime;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SCHEDULE_ID | SCHEDULE_NAME | DATETIME            | DOOR_NAME
> ----------: | :------------ | :------------------ | :--------
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-12 23:31:00 | Door 4   
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-12 23:38:00 | Door 1   
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-12 23:45:00 | Door 6   
>           1 | Schedule 1    | 2020-07-12 23:51:00 | Door 2   
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-12 10:15:00 | Door 4   
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-12 10:22:00 | Door 1   
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-12 10:30:00 | Door 1   
>           2 | Schedule 2    | 2020-07-12 10:37:00 | Door 6   
>           3 | Schedule 3    | 2020-07-12 21:59:00 | Door 4   
>           3 | Schedule 3    | 2020-07-12 22:06:00 | Door 1   
>           3 | Schedule 3    | 2020-07-12 22:13:00 | Door 1   
>           3 | Schedule 3    | 2020-07-12 22:21:00 | Door 4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3020babd17d534822061fb3090d80830)*

Comment: Thanks look great. For a test case I limited the number of schedules to 2. In prod I may have upto 100. I ALWAYS need the MMDDYYYY to be the same  for all rows. So can the code be adjusted to reset the start time WHEN the schedule_id changes. Would that be difficult

Comment: @Beefstu Updated.

Comment: @MTO apologies if I didn't articulate my requirement correctly. The second solution you provided looks like it will always generate the same time values for every schedule that's not what I need. I need a random number of rows ie 1-5 for each distinct schedule and the times should be different that's why I suggested resetting to a random time when the schedule_id changes. If the value of MMDDYYYY crosses midnight that should be the stop value and reset to a random time. The first solution was almost there, it just needed some code not to cross midnight and reset the start time. Thanks

Comment: @Beefstu Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62853758/edit) to clarify the requirements because it is not clear what you are asking. Please include a [MRE] including a detailed description of the logic because if you want a random time between `00:00` and `18:59` and then want between 1 and 5 rows for each schedule incrementing by 6-10 minutes and then you are talking about resetting times at midnight; the most you can add is 5 rows with 10 minute intervals = 50 minutes so the maximum time is `19:49` which is a long way from midnight.

Comment: @MTO I edited the question and provided a detailed explanation with examples. Thank you all for your time, patience and expertise

Answer (score -1):

***Disclaimer: I am a C# / MS-SQL developer and never used Oracle SQL or Oracle System, so please excuse my syntax.***

Before generating a random number, one needs to set a seed. Usually, timestamp in MS is a good seed for random number generation as it will be different in each execution ([Source](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random)):

```
DBMS_RANDOM.seed (val => TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYYDDMMHH24MISSFFFF'));
```

Then when you generate the date. While adding a date with a number, I am not sure if you can simply do +. If it is, please forgive me, otherwise, please try `numToDSInterval` ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277369/how-to-add-10-seconds-in-current-timestamp-sql-oracle)):

```
TRUNC(sysdate) + numToDSInterval( DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400, 'second' )
```